# Making Vectors with R

Tags: r, vector, boolean

I'm just starting to learn R in my class and we went over just the basics and I am having some difficulties with the homework assignment, especially with creating specific vectors. The problems I am struggling with are:

d)Create a boolean vector `a` of length 100 that repeats the pattern
  `TRUE`, `FALSE`, `TRUE`, `FALSE`,... Print this vector.

e) Create a numeric vector `b` of fifty 0's followed by fifty 1's. Print this vector.

What are the best/easiest/most basic methods for creating vectors like these?

Comment: Take a look at the `rep()` function for repeating values. There are options for `each=` and `times=` which will probably be handy for your needs.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `rep` and set different arguments for the two vectors that you need to create: times and each. Here is a solution

```
a<-rep(c(TRUE,FALSE),times = 50)
b<-rep(c(0,1),each = 50)
```